aws rds enable-http-endpoint not changing flag of postgres db cluster
I am running a postgres db cluster on aws and I'd like to allow an ec2 instance to make programmatic changes to the database.  When I try to run the program I get the following error:
"botocore.errorfactory.HttpEndpointNotEnabledException: An error occurred (HttpEndpointNotEnabledException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: HttpEndpoint is not enabled for resource arn:aws:rds:xxxx:xxxx:cluster:xxxx." 

However, when I try to enable HttpEndpoint through the aws cli on the ec2 instance with the command:
aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier db-xxxx --enable-http-endpoint

The flag is left unchanged.  I also tried using the --apply-immediately flag, though the docs say this shouldn't matter.  How do I enable an HttpEndpoint on a postgres 16.3 db cluster running on aws?
On an ec2 instance connected to the postgres cluster:
$ aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier db-xxxx --enable-http-endpoint

and
$ aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier db-xxxx --enable-http-endpoint --apply-immediately

both give the same response:
{
    "DBCluster: {
        "AllocatedStorage": xxxx,
        "DBClusterIdentifier": "db-xxxxx",
        ...
        "HttpEndpointEnabled: false,
        ...
}

I was expecting the response to have changed the HttpEndpointEnabled value to true:
{
    "DBCluster: {
        "AllocatedStorage": xxxx,
        "DBClusterIdentifier": "db-xxxxx",
        ...
        "HttpEndpointEnabled: true,
        ...
}

I also tried running:
aws rds enable-http-endpoint --resource-arn arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:xxxx:cluster:db-xxxx

On an Aurora PostgreSQL cluster, but ran into the following error:
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the EnableHttpEndpoint operation: Access Denied to API Version: APIDataApi

I tried opening up the Security Group to All Traffic, thinking that the command might be on some port other than 5432, but still the same error.
See comments for solution: Service not available in Ohio (us-east-2)

The modify-db-cluster option only works with Aurora Serverless V1 according to the docs, so that likely won't help you. You write about a Postgres 16.3 DB Cluster, the latest supported version that I can see is 16.2 at the time of writing this, are you sure this is correct?
Aside from that, the first docs I linked mentioned that you're supposed to use the EnableHttpEndpoint or the DisableHttpEndpoint APIs for anything other that Aurora Serverless v1.
In your case the following command should enable the Endpoint:
$ aws rds enable-http-endpoint --resource-arn <cluster-arn>


Thank you for your help.  I think the disconnect on the version is that this is a postgreSQL cluster, not an Aurora PostgreSQL cluster.  When I run the command you suggest I get a new error:  Access Denied to API Version: APIDataApi which I assume is some permissions problem.  I added AdministratorAccess to the EC2 instance and tried again, I also tried on a 16.1 Aurora PostgreSQL db cluster with same error both times.

The data API is only available for Aurora Postgres, not the "regular" Postgres AFAIK: docs. Can you add the commands you're running as well as the full error message as an edit to the original question (feel free to replace the account id)

I think I found the answer.  I've been running in Ohio (us-east-2) but the DataApi is not available for serverless v2 Aurora PostgreSQL servers in that region.  It is available in N. Virginia (us-east-1).  I will switch operations to that region.
